# Check Numeric Length Laravel

Tags: validation, laravel, laravel-4

I want to do validation checking on password in Laravel 4.2. I want the password only in numeric form and minimum length is 6. So I used as below:

```
'password'      => 'required|numeric|min:6'
```

Numeric checking is fine, but min:6 is not correct, as if I enter '000000', it return error 'password must be at least 6'. I want to ask is the numeric checking is check with the bytes size? How to check with length on numeric?

Comment: it checks length but 000000 counted as 0

Comment: If it's taken as a string, then it should work. However, I suspect it's casted to `int` at some point, and `000000 == 0` in that case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rule `digits_between` is for you.

```
'password'      => 'required|numeric|digits_between:6,20'
```

See [docs](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/validation#rule-digits-between)

If you don't want constraint for maximum length try this regex:

```
'password'      => 'required|regex:/^[0-9]{6,}$/'
```